# How to copy range and append another range

Tags: excel, vba, append

i have a data which starts with date column and has 3 groups that every group has 5 columns of same type of data. as shown below the picture.

[image]

Here is the question,
How can i create an output sheet as shown below with VBA.

Data row size is changing so fist i have to find the lastrow.

[image]

Thank You for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so clear to understand what you want for the result.
Anyway below is my guess on what you want :

```
Sub test()
Range("G2, L2").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("G2, M2, S2").Value = "F"
    
mn = Application.Min(Range("A:A"))
mx = Application.Max(Range("A:A"))
ofst = mx - mn
cnt = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), mn)
Set x = Range("A3").Offset(0, 6)
Set y = x

    For i = 1 To 3
        For ii = 1 To cnt
        Range(x, x.Offset(ofst, 0)).Value = ii
        Set x = x.Offset(ofst + 1, 0)
        Next ii
    Set y = y.Offset(0, 6)
    Set x = y
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The code assumes based on your image screenshot, where the date data range is repeating.
In the image, the date range is from 1 Jan 2020 to 18 Jan 2020. And it repeat again and again to the next row.

The code also assumes that to each group you want to insert one entire column where each has a header with value "F". (Your second image show that the "F" header is only for  Group 1).

The code will fail if the start date to end date is not repeating. For example:
From row 3 to 9, the date starts from 1 Jan 2020 to 7 Jan 2020
From row 10 to 13, the date starts from 25 Dec 2019 to 28 Dec 2019
From row 14 to 25, the date starts from 3 Jun 2021 to 14 Jun 2021
and so on.

So the code assumes something like this: 
IF:
From row 3 to 9, the date starts from 1 Jan 2020 to 7 Jan 2020
THEN:
From row 10 to 16, the date starts from 1 Jan 2020 to 7 Jan 2020
From row 17 to 23, the date starts from 1 Jan 2020 to 7 Jan 2020
and so on.

Please try to step-run the code (F8) in vba editor slowly, and see what it does on the sheet.